# Why the ratios of the coefficient of x and y of two parallel lines are equal but it is not equal to the ratio of their constant terms?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Suppose we have two lines which are parallel to each other.

- Line 1 is $a_1 x + b_1 y + c_1$
- Line 2 is $a_2 x + b_2 y + c_2$

I read in my book that $a_1/a_2 = b_1/b_2 \neq c_1/c_2$.

I tried to understand how it is possible when lines are parallel but could not figure out?

Why the ratios of the coefficient of $x$ is equal to the ratios of the coefficient of $y$ but is not equal to the ratios of the constant terms?

Comment: None of this makes sense. Both curves are parabolas, not lines. Are you referring to shifts of the same parabola?

Comment: @zugzug  thanks buddy I corrected my question.

Comment: Those are not lines because they are not equations. Do you mean $$a_1x + b_1y + c_1=0$$ $$a_2x + b_2y + c_2=0$$instead?

Comment: @MPW yes I have changed my Question.

Comment: If all the ratios were equal then they would be the same line. The differing $\frac{c_1}{c_2}$ refers to different shifts

Comment: Cannot we use subsitution or elimination method to prove that a1/a2=b1/b2 != c1/c2 ?

Comment: If you want to approach it from the point of view of solving a system of linear equations, then think about the required conditions for that system to be inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s easy to see this with [a geometric interpretation of the coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3612539/265466) of the equations, but one can also bash this out algebraically.

For the lines to be parallel, the system of equations must be inconsistent. From Cramer’s rule we know that for a system of two equations in two unknowns to be inconsistent, the denominator determinant must vanish, but the numerator determinants must be nonzero. Specifically, for the system $$a_1x+b_1y+c_1=0\\a_2x+b_2y+c_2=0$$ we must have $$\begin{vmatrix}a_1&b_1\\a_2&b_2\end{vmatrix} = 0, \begin{vmatrix}c_1&b_1\\c_2&b_2\end{vmatrix} \ne 0, \begin{vmatrix}a_1&c_1\\a_2&c_2\end{vmatrix}\ne0.$$ From the properties of determinants we know that the first determinant vanishes iff its rows are linearly dependent, which occurs when $a_1:a_2::b_1:b_2$. (The way the proportions in your question are written, $a_2$ and $b_2$ must both be nonzero.) Similarly, from the other two determinants, we see that $c_1$ and $c_2$ cannot be in the same proportion as the other coefficients, otherwise both of those determinants would also vanish. From the latter two determinants we also get the condition that $c_1$ and $c_2$ can’t both be zero, otherwise the system is indeterminate instead of inconsistent: the two equations represent the same line.

Comment: Thanks @amd for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the geometric interpretation of the coefficients $a$ and $b$ in the line's equation.
Namely, the vector of components $(a,b)$ is perpendicular to the line
$$
ax+by+c=0.
$$
Parallel lines have parallel perpendicular vectors and two vectors are parallel if and only if the ratio of their components is the same.

The coefficient $c$ only specifies one of the many lines perpendicular to the vector $(a,b)$ and can be just any number.

Comment: Thanks Andrea Mori.